# 'module' object has no attribute 'game_display'

Tags: python, pygame, display

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/home/hayden/Desktop/Platformer/platformer.py", line 65, in <module>
        game_loop()
      File "/home/hayden/Desktop/Platformer/platformer.py", line 58, in game_loop
        char(char_x,char_y)
      File "/home/hayden/Desktop/Platformer/platformer.py", line 23, in char
        pygame.game_display.blit(size,(x,y))
    AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'game_display'
    >>>
```

Code:

```
import pygame

pygame.init()

display_width = 800
display_height = 600

char_width = 128
char_height = 99

char_sprite = pygame.image.load("man.png")

framerate = 30

gravity = 5

game_display = pygame.display.set_mode((display_width,display_height))
pygame.display.set_caption("Platformer")
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

def char(x,y):
    size = pygame.transform.scale(char_sprite,(128,99))
    pygame.game_display.blit(size,(x,y))

def close():
    pygame.quit()
    quit()

def game_loop():

    char_x = display_width/2
    char_y = display_height/2
    char_x_change = 0
    char_y_change = 0
    char_speed = 5

    game_exit = False
    while not game_exit:

        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                close()
            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.type == pygame.K_W:
                    char_y_change -= char_speed
                if event.type == pygame.K_S:
                    char_y_change += char_speed
                if event.type == pygame.K_A:
                    char_x_change -= char_speed
                if event.type == pygame.K_D:
                    char_x_change += char_speed

        game_display.fill((0,0,255))

        char_x += char_x_change
        char_y += char_y_change
        char_y -= gravity
        char(char_x,char_y)

        char_y -= gravity

        pygame.display.update()
        clock.tick(framerate)

game_loop()
```

I do not know why i am getting this error and black screen. To help you better understand the code i am trying to create a 2d plat-former. I am new to programming and pygame so please try to not give a advanced explanation. For other errors like this it seems like you would have to import something but pygame is imported.

Comment: Also i forgot to say sorry for all the code.

Comment: is it possible you just need to switch `pygame.game_display` to `pygame.display`?

Comment: `pygame` has no `game_display` attribute. That's what the error is saying, and a review of the documentation confirms the same. It _does_ have a `display` attribute, but that `display` attribute has no corresponding `blit` method.

Comment: i put pygame.game_display.blit() when i shouldn't have put pygame in front of it. thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Here is your code modified. There are more errors but you must try yourself to solve and ask only if you can't do it alone. :)
When you call a function you have to send the values and parameters to it. A function does not automatically do that. See the changes I have made.

```
import pygame
from pygame import *

pygame.init()

display_width = 800
display_height = 600

char_width = 128
char_height = 99

char_sprite = pygame.image.load("test.png")

framerate = 30

gravity = 5

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((display_width,display_height))
pygame.display.set_caption("Platformer")
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

def char(x,y, screen):
    size = pygame.transform.scale(char_sprite,(128,99))
    screen.blit(size,(x,y))

def close():
    pygame.quit()
    quit()

def game_loop(screen, display_width, display_height):

    char_x = display_width/2
    char_y = display_height/2
    char_x_change = 0
    char_y_change = 0
    char_speed = 5

    game_exit = False
    while not game_exit:

        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                close()
            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.type == pygame.K_W:
                    char_y_change -= char_speed
                if event.type == pygame.K_S:
                    char_y_change += char_speed
                if event.type == pygame.K_A:
                    char_x_change -= char_speed
                if event.type == pygame.K_D:
                    char_x_change += char_speed

        screen.fill((0,0,255))

        char_x += char_x_change
        char_y += char_y_change
        char_y -= gravity
        char(char_x,char_y, screen)

        char_y -= gravity

        pygame.display.update()
        clock.tick(framerate)

game_loop(screen, display_width, display_height)
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Your key inputs are not received correctly. Read the http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/key.html section and http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html sections well and grasp the concepts well.